# JSON From Error With Angular's Http

Tags: angular, ionic3, angular-http

I have a login endpoint that I'm send a request to with angular's Http.get.  When I send incorrect login credentials I get a JSON response back from the server with an error code 401.  I can't seem to find the JSON response in the error given to the error callback. This is an ionic 3 app using angular 4.  How do I get that response body I see in PostMan out of the error given to me by Angular Http?

URL

```
http://localhost:8080/v1.0/login?rolename=Customer&username=customer00&password=wrongpass
```

Postman Response Body

```
{
   "status": "login failed - bad credentials"
}
```

console.log("Error in login: " + JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));

```
 Error in login: {
    "_body": {
       "isTrusted": true
    },
   "status": 0,
   "ok": false,
   "statusText": "",
   "headers": {},
   "type": 3,
   "url": null
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `error.json()` instead of `JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2)`?

Comment: AFAIK, `$http` is for angularjs and ionic1, from ionic2+, you should use `Http` from `HttpModule` of `@angular/http`.

Comment: @Pengyy I'm using @angular/http.  It was a typo in my question, sorry about that.  I'll update it.

Comment: @KimKern error.json() gives me this output `Error in login: {
  "isTrusted": true
}`

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, with latest ionic (angular 4.4.3)

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 4, you should be using the new `HttpClient`. With this, you will get an `HttpErrorResponse` object in case of an error. To retrieve the body in case of a server side error, you can call `(err: HttpErrorResponse) => console.log(err.error)`

Further info can be found at the official HttpClient documentation under [error handling](https://angular.io/guide/http#error-handling).

Comment: That's in angular 4.3+.  I believe ionic 3 uses angular 4.1.3.

Answer (score 0):

add this line

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: * 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

into app/index.html

[main discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45259804/ionic-2-cordova-http-error)