# Laravel not returning response after ajax call in firefox

Tags: ajax, laravel, response

Basically the ajax call is made, status OK, response is returned in other browsers but in Firefox the http response isn't returned at all.

```
$.ajax({
    type    : "GET",
    url     : 'schools_courses_calendar/'+eventId+'/associate_spot/'+spotId,
    success : function(response) {
        //console.log(response) logs an 'empty string'
        table =  $('#school_upcoming_courses').dataTable();
        table.fnDraw();
        $('#confirm-associate #spot_id').val('');
        $('#confirm-associate #event_id').val('');
    },
    error   : function(data) {
        alert('Error!');
        //console.error(data);
    }
})

return \Response::json(array(
    'success' => true,
    'errors'  => '',
    'spot'    => $l_aResponse['body']['spot']
));
```

[image]

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989052/ajax-problem-no-response-text-in-firefox-but-ok-in-ie

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: not a single error

Comment: what is your jquery version? try, method: "GET or comment the line.

Comment: print all the code of the function that sends the ajax.

Comment: `return \Response::json(array('success'=>true, 'errors'=>'', 'spot' => $l_aResponse['body']['spot']));`