# No AJAX response text

Tags: javascript, ajax, yahoo-boss-api

I think the code is right, but I don't get any response in my second alert. When I go to the website given in the first alert, I get the text I want. Why doesn't it work?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function getimages(q) {
   bossimagesrequest = new XMLHttpRequest;
   var requri = "http://boss.yahooapis.com/ysearch/images/v1/"+escape(q)+"?appid=yahoobosskey&filter=true&count=10";
   bossimagesrequest.open("GET", requri, true);
   bossimagesrequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (bossimagesrequest.readyState === 4) {
         alert(requri);
         alert(bossimagesrequest.responseText);
      }
   };
   bossimagesrequest.send();
}
</script>
```

I did replace "yahoobosskey" with my API key, so that's not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have bumped into the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You may have to use a relative path instead of your absolute `http://boss.yahooapis.com/...` path.

Related: [Empty responseText from XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941340/empty-responsetext-from-xmlhttprequest)

You may also be interested in checking out the following Stack Overflow community wiki post:

- [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy/)

Comment: So I can't use Yahoo BOSS with AJAX? I think it would be silly when Yahoo blocked other servers from BOSS, because then you have to do very much to circumvent the block. Don't I have to use AJAX for Yahoo BOSS?

Comment: @user376919: The Same Origin Policy blocks anything that does not originate from the same domain of the web document. Even a different port number is not allowed. I have no experience with Yahoo's BOSS, but you may want to check if a [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) service is served. Otherwise, you may want to check out the methods described in the SO post I linked to.

Comment: ... For example, I noticed that [Yahoo's Search API](http://developer.yahoo.com/common/json.html#callbackparam) serves JSONP. It's described as JSON using Callback.