# OpenLayers Format JSON is Returning Empty responseText String

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest, openlayers, panoramio

After a week of posting at the OpenLayers forum and not receiving responses to my questions, I have decided to look here.  I have Googled and Googled and Googled and even found a wonderful tutorial concerning this topic, in Spanish, but so well written that Google translate was able to translate it perfectly.

gisandchips.org/2010/05/04/openlayers-y-panoramio/

So I have followed this tutorial and now I am trying to access the Panoramio data API to query photos and display them on my map.  However, my code fails at the line:

**var panoramio = json.read(response.responseText);**

According to firebug and alert(response.responseText), my responseText is an empty string...

In firebug I have the GET url 
`http://localhost/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.panoramio.com%2Fmap%2Fget_panoramas.php%3Forder%3Dpopularity%26set%3Dfull%26from%3D0%26to%3D40%26minx%3D-20037508.3392%26miny%3D-20037508.3392%26maxx%3D20037508.3392%26maxy%3D20037508.3392%26size%3Dthumbnail`

this shows me valid JSON.  And I know my response object isn't null because alert(response) shows that it is getting an [object XMLHttpRequest]

Honestly I am out of ideas.  Before trying to parse JSON, I was trying to parse XML and had absolutely no luck.  I really like the idea of pulling up RSS and API data onto my map.  Below I am attaching my code, I appreciate any feedback you can offer :)

Thank you,

elshae

```
var map, popup, selectControl, selectedFeature;
var vectorLayer, panoramio_style;

Ext.onReady(function () {
    var options = {
        controls: [new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation()], //Needed to use GeoExt controls such as the zoomslider
        maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.34, -20037508.34, 20037508.34, 20037508.34),
        units: 'm',
        allOverlays: false
    }

    this.map = new OpenLayers.Map(options);

    var ghyb = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
            "Google Hybrid",
            {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID, numZoomLevels: 20}
    );

    var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
            "Google Streets", // the default
            {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, numZoomLevels: 20}
    );

    var gphy = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
            "Google Physical",
            {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN, numZoomLevels: 20}
            // used to be {type: G_PHYSICAL_MAP}
    );

    var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();

    map.addLayers([osm, gphy, gmap, ghyb]);

    OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "http://localhost/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=";

    var mapPanel = new GeoExt.MapPanel({
        title: "Map",
        map: this.map,
        center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(93.9, 29.53).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913")),
        zoom: 2,
        region: "center"
    });

    //Obtain Bbox coords
    var proj = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");
    var ext = mapPanel.map.getMaxExtent().transform(mapPanel.map.getProjectionObject(), proj);
    var minx = ext.left;
    var miny = ext.bottom;
    var maxx = ext.right;
    var maxy = ext.top;
    alert(minx + " " + miny + " " + maxx + " " + maxy);

    url = "http://www.panoramio.com/map/get_panoramas.php";
    var parameters = {
        order: 'popularity',
        set: 'full',
        from: 0,
        to: 40,
        minx: minx,
        miny: miny,
        maxx: maxx,
        maxy: maxy,
        size: 'thumbnail'
    }

    new Ext.Panel({
        width: 1800,
        height: 600,
        layout: "border",
        renderTo: document.body,
        items: [mapPanel]
    });

    OpenLayers.loadURL(url, parameters, this, showPhotos);
    //alert(OpenLayers.Request.XMLHttpRequest);

});

function showPhotos(response) {

    var json = new OpenLayers.Format.JSON();
    var panoramio = json.read(response.responseText); //Something is wrong here!!!
    var features = new Array(panoramio.photos.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < panoramio.photos.length; i++) {
        var upload_date = panoramio.photos[i].upload_date;
        var owner_name = panoramio.photos[i].owner_name;
        var photo_id = panoramio.photos[i].photo_id;
        var longitude = panoramio.photos[i].longitude;
        var latitude = panoramio.photos[i].latitude;
        var pheight = panoramio.photos[i].height;
        var pwidth = panoramio.photos[i].width;
        var photo_title = panoramio.photos[i].photo_title;
        var owner_url = panoramio.photos[i].owner_url;
        var owner_id = panoramio.photos[i].owner_id;
        var photo_file_url = panoramio.photos[i].photo_file_url;
        var photo_url = panoramio.photos[i].photo_url;

        var fpoint = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(longitude, latitude);

        var attributes = {
            'upload_date': upload_date,
            'owner_name': owner_name,
            'photo_id': photo_id,
            'longitude': longitude,
            'latitude': latitude,
            'pheight': pheight,
            'pwidth': pwidth,
            'pheight': pheight,
            'photo_title': photo_title,
            'owner_url': owner_url,
            'owner_id': owner_id,
            'photo_file_url': photo_file_url,
            'photo_url': photo_url
        }

        features[i] = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(fpoint, attributes);

    }//Outside for loop

    panoramio_style = new OpenLayers.StyleMap(OpenLayers.Util.applyDefaults({
        pointRadius: 7,
        fillColor: "red",
        fillOpacity: 1,
        strokeColor: "black",
        externalGraphic: "panoramio-marker.png"
    }, OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style["default"]));

    vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Panoramio Photos", {
        styleMap: panoramio_style
    });

    vectorLayer.addFeatures(features);

    this.map.addLayer(vectorLayer);

    selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(vectorLayer,
            {onSelect: onFeatureSelect, onUnselect: onFeatureUnselect});
    this.map.addControl(selectControl);
    selectControl.activate();
}//End showPhotos

// popups
function onPopupClose(evt) {
    selectControl.unselect(selectedFeature);
}

function onFeatureSelect(feature) {
    selectedFeature = feature;

    // HTML del PopUp
    var html = "some HTML I have here";

    popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("chicken",
            feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
            null,
            html,
            null,
            true,
            onPopupClose);

    feature.popup = popup;
    this.map.addPopup(popup);
}

function onFeatureUnselect(feature) {
    this.map.removePopup(feature.popup);
    feature.popup.destroy();
    feature.popup = null;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have bumped into the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You cannot make Ajax requests to hosts outside your domain, unless you use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP), or some other technique to get around the policy. Your request to `www.panoramio.com` is the problem, since I don't think you're hosted on the `www.panoramio.com` :)

You may want to check if panoramio offer a JSONP service. Otherwise you could check out the following Stack Overflow post for a few popular solutions to work around the Same Origin Policy (mainly the JSONP, CORS and Reverse Proxy methods):

- [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

And empty `responseText` is typical of most browsers when they block the response from third-party domains:

- [Empty responseText from XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941340/empty-responsetext-from-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: Thank you Daniel for your response and I apologize for the delay in my reply.  I used a OpenLayers ProxyHost which was supposed to allow communication with Panoramio.  So now my assumption is that Firefox is blocking me.  However, when I research this issue I keep getting Same Origin Policy.  I also tried the suggestions in the thread you sent me and had no luck :(, removing the HTTP in the proxy host etc..If you could further guide me on others steps I could take I'd gladly appreciate it.

Comment: @elshae: Is this thread relevant to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin? Note that JSONP is one of the workarounds of the same origin policy.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help Daniel.  It turns out that the same-origin policy was my problem, but with a twist :p.  I had my proxy set up on apache port 80 and had my page on a Geoserver configured in port 8080.  Since I never dealt with this sort of thing before, I was foggy on what was actually happening.  Turns out that I needed the proxy setup on Geoserver which I found here: http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/GeoServer+Proxy+Extension I appreciate you taking out the time to help me :)