# Gwt and php rpc

Tags: java, php, gwt

I am using gwt with php.

I am trying to get data fom the http://typing.lc/userInfo.php url. 
 but the following code returns nothing, but response.getText() is 200, however when i ask http://typing.lc/userInfo.php through browser it returns value.

```
        try
    {
        RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, "http://typing.lc/userInfo.php");
        builder.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        builder.sendRequest("", new RequestCallback()
        {
            @Override
            public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception)
            {
                Window.alert("Error");
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response)
            {
                Window.alert("Success: " + response.getText());

            }
        });
    }
    catch (RequestException e)
    {
        Window.alert("Exception");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably running into a [SOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941340/empty-responsetext-from-xmlhttprequest) (Same Origin Policy) issue. 
See here for [possible](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/Xsite.html) solutions.